# How to solve these errors in vocareum

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;



public class WhackAMole {
    int score;
    int molesLeft;  
    int attemptsLeft;
    char[][] molegrid;
    int actualDimension;

    WhackAMole(int numAttempts,int gridDimension){
        this.attemptsLeft=numAttempts;
        this.actualDimension=gridDimension;
        score=0;
        molesLeft=10;
        molegrid=new char[10][10];
        for(int i=0;i<gridDimension-1;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<gridDimension-1;j++) {
                molegrid[i][j]='*';
            }
        }

    }
     boolean place(int x,int y) {
        if((x<actualDimension && x>=0)&& (y<actualDimension && y>=0)) {
            molegrid[x][y]='M';
            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }

    }
     void whack(int x,int y) {
        if(molegrid[x][y]=='M'){
            score++;
            molesLeft--;
            attemptsLeft--;
            molegrid[x][y]='W';
            System.out.println("You have made a whack");
            System.out.println("You have" +attemptsLeft+"remaining tries");

        }
        else {
            attemptsLeft--;
            System.out.println("You have" +attemptsLeft+"remaining tries");
            System.out.println("("+x+","+y+") doesnt have a mole");

        }
    }
     void printGridToUser() {
        for(int i=0;i<actualDimension;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<actualDimension;j++) {
                if(molegrid[i][j]=='M') {
                    molegrid[i][j]='*';
                    System.out.print(molegrid[i][j] );
                    molegrid[i][j]='M';
                }
                else {
                System.out.print(molegrid[i][j] );
                }
            }
                System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
  void printGrid() {
      for(int i=0;i<actualDimension;i++) {

          for(int j=0;j<actualDimension;j++) {
              System.out.print(molegrid[i][j]);
          }
          System.out.print("\n");
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     WhackAMole a=new WhackAMole(50,10);
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
          Random randomGenerator = new Random();
          Random randomGenerator1 = new Random();
         int molelocationx= randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
         int molelocationy= randomGenerator1.nextInt(9);
        boolean b= a.place(molelocationx, molelocationy);
        if(b==true) {
            System.out.println("Mole placed");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Mole not placed");
        }
     }
      System.out.println("You have maximum 50 chances");
      for(int j=0;j<50;j++) {
          Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter first coordinate");
          int userlocx=scanner.nextInt();
          Scanner scanner1=new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter second coordinate");
          int userlocy=scanner1.nextInt();

          if(userlocx==-1 && userlocy==-1)
          {
              System.out.println("Exiting");
              System.out.println("Your score is"+a.score);
              a.printGrid();

              System.exit(1);

          }
          else if(userlocx>9 || userlocx<-1 || userlocy>9 || userlocy<-1 ){
              System.out.println("Invalid");
              continue;
          }
          else {
                 a.whack(userlocx, userlocy);
                 a.printGridToUser();
                 if(a.molesLeft==0) {
                     System.out.println("You have won!!");
                     System.exit(2);
                 }

          }
      }
      System.out.println("Game over try again next time");
  }
}
```

ERRORS SHOWN
/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
int actualRow = whack.moleGrid.length;
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
/home/ccc_v1_c79431__48717/asn12900_Whack_a_Mole/asn12901_JUnit/asnlib/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
int actualCol = whack.moleGrid[i].length;
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
/home/ccc_v1_c79431__48717/asn12900_Whack_a_Mole/asn12901_JUnit/asnlib/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
char actualChar = whack.moleGrid[i][j];
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
/home/ccc_v1_c79431__48717/asn12900_Whack_a_Mole/asn12901_JUnit/asnlib/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
char actualOneOne = whack.moleGrid[1][1];
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
/home/ccc_v1_c79431__48717/asn12900_Whack_a_Mole/asn12901_JUnit/asnlib/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
assertEquals("Expected char at (1, 2): M, but actual: " + whack.moleGrid[1][2], 'M', whack.moleGrid[1][2]);
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
/home/ccc_v1_c79431__48717/asn12900_Whack_a_Mole/asn12901_JUnit/asnlib/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
assertEquals("Expected char at (1, 2): M, but actual: " + whack.moleGrid[1][2], 'M', whack.moleGrid[1][2]);
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
/home/ccc_v1_c79431__48717/asn12900_Whack_a_Mole/asn12901_JUnit/asnlib/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
assertEquals("Mole placed at wrong place: (" + i + ", " + j + ")", '*', whack.moleGrid[i][j]);
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
/home/ccc_v1_c79431__48717/asn12900_Whack_a_Mole/asn12901_JUnit/asnlib/WhackAMoleTestGrader.java:139: error: cannot find symbol
assertEquals("(1, 1) doesn't have a mole", 'M', whack.moleGrid[1][1]);
^
symbol: variable moleGrid
location: variable whack of type WhackAMole
8 errors
(Failed)
Command exited with non-zero status 1

Comment: You cannot expect us to debug and fix your code. For a start, start searching for these errors one by one

Comment: tell what is your code error. and we cannot debug your code and fix it.first analysis your code and tell the error.

Answer (score 0):

**I can compile you code and there is no errors.**

1) There is no actualRow in your code, but it is first error. Others are the same...

I think you need to write code that would be called by testing program. And they assume you have actualRow and other. Read your task again...

2) It doesn't look like a java compiler output. It looks like code compiled with C++ or Python compiler. Check what language you have to use for submission OR maybe there is check-box for selecting language of your submit.